# How are Firebase Events calculated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a Firebase event.  According to Firebase, the event was triggered 878 times in the past 3 months by 161 users.  That should be about 5.5 times per user.  But it claims that it was triggered 10 times per user.  By changing the date range, I get the same confusing results (about double what is expected).

[image]

What am I not understanding here?  Why don't these numbers add up?

Comment: Why did you delete the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309719/can-i-subscribe-to-a-generic-action-with-a-concrete-method ? I was about to give you an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity It did that "This question has been closed.  Would you like to delete it or edit it?"  So I deleted it.  I undeleted it though.  I would love to hear your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Best I could think of would be for example if a user didn't select anything their vote might not be counted, so it could approx 87 users actually doing something? although I will admit it looks odd to me.

More information here might help you in regards to how certain events are calculated if my attempted analysis was incorrect:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?visit_id=637443541013685645-1067495433&rd=1

Answer (score -1):

- Count per user: average number of times per user that the event was triggered

It **doesn't** have to make users/event.One user has click 20 times other 1 time and thats 10 count per user

So if 100 users clicked 20 times and 61 users 1 times should be different, but because we dont know exactly how many times each use has clicked we assume that one user has click 20 times other 1 time

The metrics reflect different information depending on the event

From Firebase docs:

Summary table
The table lists the events that were triggered in your app during your active date range.

The table shows the following metrics for each event:

- Count: number of times the event was triggered List item
- Users: number of users who triggered the event

Click an event in the table to see a detail report for that event. The information in each detail report varies according to the event.

Event metrics
The following metrics are provided for each event:

Event count: number of times the event was triggered

Users: number of users who triggered the event

Count per user: average number of times per user that the event was triggered

Value: sum of all VALUE parameters supplied with the event. Use this context-sensitive metric to track any data that is valuable to your app (e.g., revenue, time, distance).