# Can I subscribe to a generic Action with a concrete method?

Tags: c#, generics, publish-subscribe

[See Enigmativity's answer for a much clearer phrasing of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310013/1889720)

---

I have a generic `Action` that I am registering for, and then casting to the type I am expecting:

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

public static Action<IMyInterface> MyAction;

public class MyClass : IMyInterface { }

public void Subscribe()
{
    MyAction<MyClass> += MyMethod;
}

public void MyMethod(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
    var myClass = (MyClass)myInterface;
}
```

But I want to be able to subscribe with a method that already dictates the type so I can avoid the extra step of casting.  Is it possible to only subscribe to MyActions such that IMyInterface has a specific type?  So that `MyMethod` can be like this:

```
public void MyMethod(MyClass myClass)
{

}
```

The reason I am trying to do this is because I am writing a messaging system which uses the specific type.  I am using generics to determine which messages to subscribe to.  I don't think this part affects my question, but here is what that looks like:

```
private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>> subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>>();

public void SubscribeMessage<TMessage>(Action<IMessage> callback)
    where TMessage : IMessage
{
    var type = typeof(TMessage);
    if (subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        if (!subscribers[type].Contains(callback))
        {
            subscribers[type].Add(callback);
        }
        else
        {
            LogManager.LogError($"Failed to subscribe to {type} with {callback}, because it is already subscribed!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        subscribers.Add(type, new List<Action<IMessage>>());
        subscribers[type].Add(callback);
    }
}

public void UnsubscribeMessage<TMessage>(Action<IMessage> callback)
    where TMessage : IMessage
{
    var type = typeof(TMessage);
    if (subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        if (subscribers[type].Contains(callback))
        {
            subscribers[type].Remove(callback);
        }
        else
        {
            LogManager.LogError($"Failed to unsubscribe from {type} with {callback}, because there is no subscription of that type ({type})!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LogManager.LogError($"Failed to unsubscribe from {type} with {callback}, because there is no subscription of that type ({type})!");
    }
}

//The use case given MyClass implements IMessage
public void Subscribe()
{
    SubscribeMessage<MyClass>(MyMethod);
}

public void MyMethod(IMessage myMessage)
{
    var myClass = (MyClass)myMessage;
}
```

So is it possible for me to subscribe to a generic `Action` with a method that has a concrete type?

Comment: _"is it possible for me to subscribe to a generic Action with a method that has a concrete type?"_ -- **did you try it?** What happened? What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, I have tried everything I can think of.  I do not know how to do it.  If you feel I have shown insufficient research, please let me know what else you would like to see.

Comment: By the way, your use of a public non-`readonly` variable here is bad code. You should be using a proper C# `event` declaration. It will work the same, but will make sure that only the implementing class has access to the delegate field.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That code at the top is just to explain the question.  The code at the bottom is what I actually have in the project so far.

Comment: The short version is "no", because it wouldn't be safe. If you could assign e.g. a method taking as the parameter `MyClass` to a delegate type `Action<IMyInterface>`, then anyone with a reference to that delegate type could pass _any_ `IMyInterface` reference to your method, even if it's not the `MyClass` your method _requires_. The duplicate offers advice for one scenario where a fully generic work-around can work, but note that it works by fundamentally changing the design of the code to one that _is_ type-safe.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you peter.  I was afraid that would be the answer, but I figured I would ask.  I will keep using my current implementation.  (Just the bottom half of the code...not the top half.  Don't worry!)  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Evorlor - Your code for `SubscribeMessage` and `UnsubscribeMessage` doesn't really seem to do anything useful. There's no way that that code and the `MyAction += MyMethod;` can be related. You must be missing some code for `SendMessage` (or similr) to bind it al together. And if you had such a method then you could write what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types in your question seemed to be a bit garbled - `IMyInterface` at the top of the question and `IMessage` in the bottom part. I've assumed these interfaces and basic methods:

```
public interface IMessage { }

public class MyClass1 : IMessage { }
public class MyClass2 : IMessage { }

public void MyMethod1(MyClass1 myClass1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MyMethod1");
}

public void MyMethod2(MyClass2 myClass1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MyMethod2");
}
```

Now, I've further simplified your code to not have a `SubscribeMessage` and an `UnsubscribeMessage` method as this will force you to maintain a reference to the original delegate to remove a delegate. It's easier to have a single `Subscribe` method that returns an `IDisposable` that lets you unsubscribe. It's much easier to hold a bunch of disposables than many different types of delegates - otherwise it's an "out of the frying pan and into the fire" kind of thing.

Here's all you need for `Subscribe`:

```
private Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>> _subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>>();

public IDisposable Subscribe<TMessage>(Action<TMessage> callback) where TMessage : IMessage
{
    var type = typeof(TMessage);
    if (!_subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        _subscribers.Add(type, new List<Delegate>());
    }
    _subscribers[type].Add(callback);
    return new ActionDisposable(() => _subscribers[type].Remove(callback));
}
```

I've removed the need to check for duplicates. That should be a responsibility of the calling code. There are situations where calling a delegate twice might be valid. Leave it to the calling code to make sure it's a sane thing to do or not.

I've also used a `List<Delegate>` as that enables any delegate type to be stored.

Here's the `ActionDisposable` class you need:

```
public sealed class ActionDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private int _disposed;

    public ActionDisposable(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _disposed, 1) == 0)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}
```

And now here's `Send`:

```
public void Send<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : IMessage
{
    var type = typeof(TMessage);
    if (_subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        var subscriptions = _subscribers[type].Cast<Action<TMessage>>().ToArray();
        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            subscription(message);
        }
    }
}
```

So to call all of this code you can do:

```
IDisposable subscription1 = Subscribe<MyClass1>(MyMethod1);
IDisposable subscription2 = Subscribe<MyClass2>(MyMethod2);

Send(new MyClass1());
Send(new MyClass2());

subscription1.Dispose();

Send(new MyClass1());
Send(new MyClass2());
```

The result I get is:

```
MyMethod1
MyMethod2
MyMethod2
```

It clearly is subscribing and unsubscribing, and it's only calling the delegates for the type of message passed. I think that covers off on what you're trying to do.